# Html.BeginForm Doesn't seem to want to post back to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.beginform

My MVC razor form will not post back to my controller.  I have tried various combinations of parameters in the BeginForm Method to no avail.

**View Code**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateSurveyData", "Site"))
{
  ...
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Site Controller Method**

```
public ActionResult UpdateSurveyData()
{
   // Code Never Reaches this point
   ...
}
```

The rendered html looks like this

```
<form action="/Site/UpdateSurveyData" method="post"></form>
```

I should mention that I am trying to render this form in a kendoUI modal window and if I use `<form></form>` without using the Html helper, it works as expected.

Comment: So it did not render the submit button ? If yes, when you submit what is happening ? Do you have any js code which is intercepting the button click event and preventing the default behavior ?

Comment: Is the method you have shown marked with `[HttpPost]` (and why does it return a `JsonResult`?

Comment: also add FormMethod.Post after controller name if it works.

Comment: I looks like the submit button is outside of the form element

Comment: I did try [HttpPost] at one point on the method.  Didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't get why the submit button didn't render in the form.  Or for that matter any of the other controls.

Comment: @JackFairfield I've had hit and miss success with the using (Html.BeginForm) approach; for reasons unknown to me, I had the same problem you did.  The reason is the form object disposes before the rendering of the other controls (on dispose, the end form tag renders).  Hence why even though your code might be right, it may not behave as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had hit and miss success with the using (Html.BeginForm) approach; for reasons unknown to me, I had the same problem you did.  The real reason is the form object disposes too early, before the rendering of the other controls (on dispose, the end form tag renders).  Hence why even though your code might be right, it may not behave as expected.  Still havent figured out why the dispose happens early.

If you are using any kendo controls (the MVC wrappers), I don't know if there is something within the framework that might affect the rendering process, but I personally had the problem with just the core framework.

Comment: Thanks Brian, this helped me solve this issue.  I ended up ditching the Html.BeginForm helper and instead used raw <form></form> elements.